# Sites popup issues

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app, ipad

With version 1.2.0.141 I'm having the following two issues on my iPad:

1. If you open sites, select a site that is not in the sitebar it opens below the sites menu on the left. If you now select sites again the red focus bar is gone.
   [image]
2. If you select another page above the sites menu the newly added site disappears (which is OK). But if you now go back to sites the red focus bar appears but the sites icon itself is gone.
   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An earlier fix was missing this use case in some of the selection logic. Because showing a non-favorite site appends it to the end of the menu section, the selection logic wrongly assumed this last item was the "more sites" item.

This should be fixed in **beta version 1.2.0.142**.